# new line expression in XML

Tags: xml, zend-framework, newline, expression

I create an XML in PHP Zend framework using DOM Class. To put a new line in XML element textnode an expression **`&lt;<BR>&gt;`** is passed. But when I pass a string with `&lt;<BR>&gt;` the generated XML will have **`&amp;lt;BR&amp;gt;`** instead actual expression `&lt;<BR>&gt;`. and so, the display of data from XML will print `<BR>` instead of new line.

How to prevent modification of the expression `&lt;<BR>&gt;` ?

Answer (score 1):

`<BR>` is HTML for "a line break", not XML. If you were to insert it, raw, into an XML document then you would just have a start tag for the unknown BR element and no end tag. This would cause the document to be not well-formed and XML parsers to throw a critical error when they encountered the next close tag (which wouldn't be `</BR>`).

If you want to express a new line as markup, then you need to:

1. Make sure that the XML application you are using has markup to represent a new line
2. Create that markup as an element (while there are often methods to insert a chunk of raw XML into a document, they are a good way to accidentally break things and inserting a series of text nodes and elements is safer).

Comment: when I manually change `&amp;lt;BR&amp;gt;` to `&lt;<BR>&gt;` into my XML application then it creates a line break. So, anyhow I need to insert `&lt;<BR>&gt;` via string through PHP to create XML text node having exactly what I have passed through PHP string.

Comment: It sounds like the XML parser is broken then. Fix it so it can deal with real XML instead of trying to mangle the XML.

Comment: I guess XML writer is not working properly. It is parsed very well.

Comment: If it parses it after you edit the XML to make it non-well-formed, then the parser is broken.